# Accept websocket use tcp .net very slow?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, websocket

I created a .NET class socket using a websocket server. When my browser tries to connect to socket on my program, I see that the method 'accept socket' is called very slow or seconds after my browser connects.  I tried creating many connections but the socket accepts a websocket every second. I tried alchemy websocket too, results like my code.

After I used Miscrosoft websocket on IIS8, I noticed that the speed is pretty good.

I am not experimental.

My code (express)

```
class Connection
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    Socket socket;
    bool IsAuthencation;
    public Connection(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
    }

    void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = socket.EndReceive(result);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                if (!IsAuthencation)
                {
                    byte[] tmp = new byte[count];
                    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, tmp, 0, count);
                    string Request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmp);
                    if (Request.Contains("GET"))
                    {
                        if (!IsAuthencation)
                        {
                            int indexStart = Request.IndexOf("Sec-WebSocket-Key: ");
                            int indexEnd = Request.IndexOf("Sec-WebSocket-Version:");
                            string key = Request.Substring(indexStart + 19, indexEnd - indexStart - 21);
                            string magic = string.Concat(key, "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
                            string base64 = "";
                            using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
                            {
                                byte[] bufferMagic = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(magic));
                                base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bufferMagic);
                            }

                            Byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Connection: Upgrade" + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Upgrade: websocket" + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + base64
                                + Environment.NewLine
                                + Environment.NewLine);
                            socket.BeginSend(response, 0, response.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);
                            IsAuthencation = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
            }
            else
            {
                // disconnect
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    void OnSend(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            socket.EndSend(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

}
class Program
{
    static List<Connection> clients;
    static Socket socket;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        clients = new List<Connection>();
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 30000);
        socket.Bind(endPoint);
        socket.Listen(0);
        socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptAsync), null);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void AcceptAsync(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a new connection");
        Socket s = socket.EndAccept(result);
        clients.Add(new Connection(s));
        socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptAsync), null);
    }


}
```

you can try command javascript var socket=  new WebSocket("ws://localhost:30000"), i not see a problem in my code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept the socket, and handle it asynchronously, and then back to accepting more sockets straightaway.

**UPDATE**

After seeing your code, it seems you are accepting connections asynchronously. How are you creating those test connections? If you are creating too many you are maybe saturating the app.

I think I see the problem, why are you setting the [socket backlog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to 0? Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4254062/307976) from SO.

Try to put a bigger value: `socket.Listen(100);`

Comment: i edit code on topic, you can help check error logic in code?

Comment: i send command on brower chrome, you use chrome, express f12, click to tab console, write command var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:30000")

Comment: i see very slow although i change to socket.Listen(100). result test of you?