# max concurrent, qps, and tcp backlog

Tags: node.js, tcp

Nodejs set backlog 512 by default. Does this mean a nodejs server can only accept less than 512 client requests at a single timing point?

If nodejs server spends 20ms processing one request, is the max qps/tps is 50?

I was confused by max concurrent clients, qps, and tcp backlog. (please consider nodejs only one process)

Thank you!

Comment: *"Tcp backlog number is the max number of clients a server can handle simultaneously, right?"* - no, it's not. Possible duplicate of [What is "backlog" in TCP connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594400/what-is-backlog-in-tcp-connections), [What value of backlog should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002868/), [Question about listening and backlog for sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253454/).

Comment: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253454/question-about-listening-and-backlog-for-sockets) does answer my question. so close this thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question about listening and backlog for sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253454/question-about-listening-and-backlog-for-sockets)